# Scroll NSTableView to selection

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

OK, this is my situation :

- I have an `NSMutableArray` bound to an `NSTableView`, via an `NSArrayController`.
- I'm manipulating the table view's selection (trigger by keyboard), using `NSArrayController`'s `selectNext:` and `selectPrevious:`

The thing is : The selection **does** change, but the table view doesn't scroll to the current selection, so that its content is visible.

What should I do? Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a method in `NSTableView`

```
- (void)scrollRowToVisible:(NSInteger)row;
```

That will scroll to the specified `row`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've already tried it and it works. However, there is still some subtle issue : a) although I'm doing `[myTableView scrollRowToVisible:[myTableView selectedRow]]` (right after `selectNext:` and `selectPrevious:`, it doesn't scroll to the *current* line, but the one either before or after it (respectively). b) even after a `[myTableView scrollRowToVisible:[myTableView selectedRow]+1]` (after `selectNext:`), it *does* show up, but scrolling is *not* smooth. (**HINT** : The table view is *not* in focus). Any idea?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, actually I created a project to check, and it worked for me, as I used     `- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    [self.array addObject:@"Anoop"];
    [self.myTable reloadData];
    [self.myTable scrollRowToVisible:self.array.count-1];
}`

Comment: Had the same issue as @Dr.Kameleon. I guess it's because when you invoke `selectPrevious`, the view's properties will not immediately change. Dispatching `scrollRowToVisible` for "later" helped, too. It's not pretty, but it's less of a hack to mitigate the race conditions than +/-1: `DispatchQueue.main.async { tableView.scrollRowToVisible(tableView.selectedRow) }`